# How to create straps on character clothing?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm working on a character, but I've run into an issue on how I would make "strap" clothing like a belt or a vambrace, preferably that the character can remove at times.
[image: Like Sintel's belt and bits of armor.]

Like Sintel's belt and bits of armor.

Also, though it's not required, how do I make things ON the belt itself? Like a knife sheath strapped on to it.

Comment: Unclear as to what issues you're running into. However, I might suggest going with other animation techniques rather than cloth-sims as your tag suggests you are trying. Vertex group rigging might be a good way to do it.